# Create dynamically sequential tasks in Luigi

Tags: python, dynamic, etl, sequential, luigi

```
import luigi

class FileToStaging(ImportToTable):
    filename = Luigi.Parameter(default = '')
    #import file from some folder to a staging database
    def requires(self):
         return luigi.LocalTarget(self.filename)
    
    #truncate table
    #load the file into staging


class StgToOfficial(RunQuery):
    filename = Luigi.Parameter
    # run a process in the database to load data from staging to the final table
    def requires(self):
        return FileToStaging(self.filename)

    # run query


class LoadFileGroups(luigi.WrapperTask):

    def requires(self):
        list_of_files = get_list_of_files_currently_in_folder() # The folder can have an arbitrary number of files inside
        for file in list_of_files:
            yield(StgToOfficial(filename = file))
```

Hello, community,

I'm new to Luigi and trying to build an ETL process with the framework.

Imagine I have a process similar to the previous snippet of pseudo code. The process must check a folder and get the list of files inside. Then, one by one, import to staging database and run a process to load the data in staging to the final table.

The problem is that, with the previous solution, all the files loading into the staging table (followed by the loading process of each file) is run in parallel, which cannot happen. How can I force Luigi to execute the tasks sequentially? Only when a file finishes the load in the final table, import the next one and so on. (Check the draft below for a simplified draft)

[Draft of the structure I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPcND.png)

I know that I should use the requires method to ensure the sequence, but how can I do it dinamically for a unknown number of files to be loaded?

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a recursive pattern in the requires() method according to the answer from Peter Weissbrod in the following discution:
https://groups.google.com/g/luigi-user/c/glvU_HxYmr0/m/JvV3xgsiAwAJ

Here is the solution proposed by Peter:

> Here is a snippet which isnt precisely tailored to your needs but at the same time you might find useful. Consider a "sql" directory like this:

```
  ~ :>ll somedir/sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pweissbrod authenticatedusers   513 Jan 27 09:15 stage01_test.sqltemplate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pweissbrod authenticatedusers  1787 Jan 28 13:57 stage02_test.sqltemplate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pweissbrod authenticatedusers  1188 Jan 28 13:57 stage03_test.sqltemplate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pweissbrod authenticatedusers 13364 Jan 29 07:16 stage04_test.sqltemplate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pweissbrod authenticatedusers  1344 Jan 28 13:57 stage05_test.sqltemplate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pweissbrod authenticatedusers  1983 Jan 28 17:03 stage06_test.sqltemplate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pweissbrod authenticatedusers  1224 Jan 28 16:05 stage07_test.sqltemplate

# Consider a luigi task with a dynamic requires method like this:
class BuildTableTask(luigi.Task):
    table = luigi.Parameter(description='the name of the table this task (re)builds')
    def requires(self):
        tables = [f.split('_')[0] for f in os.listdir('sql') if re.match(f'stage[0-9]+[a-z]*_{config().environment}', f)]
        prereq = next(iter([t for t in sorted(tables, reverse=True) if t < self.table]), None)
        yield BuildTableTask(table=prereq) or []
   
    def run(self):
        with open(f'sql/{self.table}_{config().environment}.sqltemplate'.format(**config().to_dict())) as sqltemplate:
            sql = sqltemplate.read().format(**config().to_dict())
        db.run(f'create table {config().srcdbname}.{self.table} stored as orc as {sql}')

the task tree is built by observing the files in that directory:
 └─--[BuildTableTask-{'table': 'stage07'} (COMPLETE)]
    └─--[BuildTableTask-{'table': 'stage06'} (COMPLETE)]
       └─--[BuildTableTask-{'table': 'stage05'} (COMPLETE)]
          └─--[BuildTableTask-{'table': 'stage04'} (COMPLETE)]
             └─--[BuildTableTask-{'table': 'stage03'} (COMPLETE)]
                └─--[BuildTableTask-{'table': 'stage02'} (COMPLETE)]
                   └─--[BuildTableTask-{'table': 'stage01'} (COMPLETE)]
```